# How do you run Git after downloading and installing the .dmg from http://git-scm.com/?

Tags: git, operating-system, osx-lion

How do you run Git in Mac OS X Lion after downloading Git v1.7.8.2 from http://git-scm.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You run it from the terminal.

If you have to ask, I guess you need a GUI. 
 See

- [The best Mac Git GUI client (2011)](http://www.devdaily.com/mac-os-x/best-mac-osx-git-gui-client)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83789/what-is-the-best-git-gui-on-osx

GitX is the most commonly used one. SmartGit is great, if you will pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run `git`

http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/06/21/mac-git-installation-on-osx/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage your git version then try a [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) install.

After this you can do `$ brew install git` in your terminal and there it is.